# How to configure jdbc fallback for mariadb connector

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want my application to always try best to connect to the first node of galera multi-master database cluster

My applications are using mariadb jdbc connector to connect to the database. Because of galera's known limitations, I often get conflicts. One solution would be to force the applications to connect to only one node for writing. 
According to the mariadb connector documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j/),  I can use `sequentail` mode, so that the connector will try hosts in order. But the problem with `sequential` is that it doesn't fallback, and so I still cannot guarantee that all applications will connect to the same database node.

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the mariadb knowledge page is not quite clear.

Here's what I found about Mariadb connector after some tests:

1. *Basic Failover*
   If no failover mode is specified, it uses *Basic Failover*.(eg. `jdbc:mariadb://host1,host2`) In this mode, the JDBC driver will try best to connect to `host1` until it becomes unavailable. After failover happens, if `host1` comes back, it will try to fall back to `host1` and disconnect other hosts.
2. *Sequential Mode*
   This mode is pretty much the same as Basic Failover except that the JDBC driver sticks to the second node and does not fall back to the first node even if it comes back
3. *Failover*
   My understanding is that `jdbc:mariadb:failover` in Mariadb JDBC connector is the equivalent of `jdbc:mysql:loadbalance` in MySQL JDBC connector. The connector will connect to all nodes in read&write mode unless you specify `(type=slave)`.
4. Replication
   With `jdbc:mariadb:replication://host1,host2,host3`, the JDBC driver will connect to `host1` in read&write mode, and all other nodes in read mode